# I am getting NameError: name 'data' is not defined from selenium webscrape, but I have defined it in the code, can anyone see what';s wrong?

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def races(main_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(main_url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    races = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('time-location')
    races = [race.text[:5] for race in races]
    races = [race.replace(':', '') for race in races]

    driver.close()

    return races

import pandas as pd    

def scrape(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('racecard-ajax-link')[1].click()

    WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//* [@id="tab-racecard-sectional-times"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/button')))
```

This is where I store the web scrape results to the variable data so struggling to see what is causing the error.

```
    data = [main]


    for horse in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('card-item'):
        horseName = horse.find_element_by_class_name('form-link').text
        times = horse.find_elements_by_class_name('sectionals-time')
        times = [time.text for time in times]
        print('{}: {}'.format(horseName, times))
    print()

    driver.close()

    return data

def main():
    date = '6-October-2018'
    main_url = 'http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Wolverhampton/' + date
    for race in races(main_url):
        url = main_url + '/' + race
        print(url)
        scrape(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At this point the webscraper returns all of the data results within sublime, but it doesn't save to the csv file as it throws an NameError: name 'data' is not defined after the df = pd.DataFrame(data)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("jan_1")
```

Comment: This is local versus global variable, see e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/)

Comment: Thanks but forgive me for being really dense I'm still not sure how to resolve this after reading that link. Am I to define the variable as global or insert "df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("jan_1") inside the code somewhere? I've tried both with no success.

Comment: From your code it isn't clear where the `df = pd.DataFrame(data)` is or should be placed. Depending on the context it may be placed into the `for`-loop in `main`. As `scrape` returns the data you could there write `data = scrape(url)` and after that the `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the `data = [main]` also doesn't make much sense and `data` isn't filled with the real data. Your code may have too many issues to solve them here.